# Windows 8 Python doesn't work

Tags: python

I installed python 3.5.2 on Windows 8.1, I executed the python-3.5.2-amd64.exe installer.
Nothing bad happened.
I was searching the Python35 folder in C:\ , but actually is in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35

I opened python.exe and I got an error: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing.

How can I make it works?

I already have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.50727 and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I retagged the question, since it has nothing to do about *programming* in c++.

Comment: Ok, thanks, It was on suggested tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install this windows update:

[KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)

Or, I think you need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Yea, there's a problem... I never updated my windows, I stopped my windows update service. Now, when I started it just for this update, the CPU goes to 30-40% forever and nothing happen.

Comment: Should I try to install the vc_redist.x64.exe?
I don't think waiting the windows update process to finish is a good idea.. I already waited 40 mins. and.. as I said, nothing happened.

Comment: There is an update that fix the proc overload ... don't remember which one. Anyway, it can take up to 8 hours (and probably more).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it.

I installed the anaconda python, more preciously, miniconda: http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

The software has been installed in `C:\Users\NAME\Miniconda3`, where I noticed that `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` and other files like this is in that folder, where the miniconda was installed. Those files fill the missing files displayed on main error.

I thought I can only use the python through the miniconda launcher, but it works anyway.

Comment: Thanks bro! You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I did find the missing files in a directory under C:\windows\WinSxS, just do a lookup for the required file and then paste all the files in that directory in C:\Windows\System32. That solved the problem for me.